# Porque não consigo enviar o carácter "+" via post em um simples formulário HTML?

Tags: php, javascript, html

Fiz uma simples pagina em html que ao receber o login e uma senha ele enviar para uma outra página onde os dados são verificados, o problema é que quando colocar o carácter **"+"** na senha ele simplesmente não chega no post, o que chega é um vazio **" "**.

O cabeçalho do formulário esta assim:

```
<form action="VerificaLogin.php"method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" accept-charset="iso-8859-1">
```

Já troquei o charset para **UTF-8** e não deu, ja mudei o enctype para **application/x-www-form-urlencoded** e também não deu certo.

como posso resolver esse problema ?

Comment: Tenta colocar uma barra "/" antes do "+"

Comment: Poste mais detalhes do seu código, tanto de envio quanto de recebimento dos dados...

Comment: Coloque o código de `VerificaLogin.php`

Comment: Vou testar o que o amigo ali embaixo falou, se não der vou postar o código aqui.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fiz um tratamento com JavaScript, antes de enviar a requisição eu uso a função **encodeURIComponent()** para codificar a string de senha antes validar o login no servidor, com isso consegui usar qualquer tipo de caractere especial sem problema.

Answer (score 1):

Provavelmente você está usando algum par de aspas no local errado, seu php deve estar entendendo o **+** como adição e não como um caractere.